python strings from sublists in other sublists
this function is supposed to check if elements from sublists in colors are present in the sublists contained in food and create a dictionary based on the colors initials contained in categ_cols
def group_by_category(categs_names, categs_subs, text_subs):
    temp_dict = {name: [] for name in categs_names}

    for categ_index, category_list in enumerate(categs_subs):
        for substring in category_list:
            for sublist in text_subs:
                for text in sublist:
                    if substring in text:
                        temp_dict[categs_names[categ_index]].append(text)
                    else:
                        temp_dict[categs_names[categ_index]].append('None')
    return temp_dict

categs_cols = ['y', 'r', 'g']
food = [['banana is yellow', 'apple is red', 'pear is green' ] , ['lettuce is green' ,'pasta is yellowish','sugar is brown'] ]
colors = [[ 'yellow', 'yellowish'  ], ['red'], ['green']]
grouped_cols = group_by_category(categs_cols, colors, food)
print(grouped_cols)

the expected result is the following
{'y': ['banana is yellow', 'pasta is yellowish'], 'r': ['None', 'apple is red'], 
 'g': ['pear is green', 'lettuce is green']}

but instead I am getting this
 {'y': ['banana is yellow', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'pasta is yellowish', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'pasta is yellowish', 'None'], 'r': ['None', 'apple is red', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'], 'g': ['None', 'None', 'pear is green', 'lettuce is green', 'None', 'None']}

I tried with a break underneath this
if substring in text:   
    temp_dict[categs_names[categ_index]].append(text)

but it had no effect

The else statement is going to add None every time a food item does not match the current keyword. What you want instead is to check at the very end of the current category_list (i.e. the end of the outermost loop) if the list of matches is empty, then you add None. The result should look something like this:
def group_by_category(categs_names, categs_subs, text_subs):
    temp_dict = dict()

    for categ_index, category_list in enumerate(categs_subs):
        matches = [] # Here is the list of matches
        for substring in category_list:
            for sublist in text_subs:
                for text in sublist:
                    if substring in text:
                        matches.append(text)
        if len(matches) == 0: # Only add None if the search came up empty
            matches.append("None")
        temp_dict[categs_names[categ_index]] = matches
    return temp_dict

categs_cols = ['y', 'r', 'g', 'e']
food = [['banana is yellow', 'apple is red', 'pear is green' ] , ['lettuce is green' ,'pasta is yellowish','sugar is brown']]
colors = [[ 'yellow', 'yellowish'  ], ['red'], ['green'], ['empty']]
grouped_cols = group_by_category(categs_cols, colors, food)
print(grouped_cols)

""" >>> {'y': ['banana is yellow', 'pasta is yellowish', 'pasta is yellowish'], 'r': ['apple is red'], 'g': ['pear is green', 'lettuce is green'], 'e': ['None']} """


you are wrong too since your code doesn't produce what I am looking for

I believe this answer is fine. If you don't want the {'e': ['None']} in the end result just remove the last items from categs_colsandcolors`

it is not because i need to produce 'None' when the condition is not met to assure that all dict categories have the same length. is also important that 'None' is included exactly when the condition is not met since the indexing is important. furthermore, your solution has a duplicate string in the 'y' key

Right I misunderstood that. I believe at the end you can check the maximum length of items across categories and append enough None's to the rest to match the required output

If you do a little input reshaping via zip() and a flattening comprehension then you can do:
def group_by_category(categs_names, categs_subs, text_subs):
    retval = {}
    for categs_id, categs_words in zip(categs_names, categs_subs):
        for text_sub in [cell for row in text_subs for cell in row]:
            if any(word in text_sub for word in categs_words):
                retval.setdefault(categs_id, []).append(text_sub)
    return retval

categs_cols = [
    'y',
    'r',
    'g'
]

colors = [
    ['yellow', 'yellowish'],
    ['red'],
    ['green']
]

food = [
    ['banana is yellow', 'apple is red', 'pear is green' ],
    ['lettuce is green' ,'pasta is yellowish','sugar is brown']
]

print(group_by_category(categs_cols, colors, food))

Giving you:
{
    'y': ['banana is yellow', 'pasta is yellowish'],
    'r': ['apple is red'],
    'g': ['pear is green', 'lettuce is green']
}

To include the None you might try:
def group_by_category(color_ids, color_synonyms_list, phrase_lists):
    retval = {}
    for color_id, color_synonyms in zip(color_ids, color_synonyms_list):
        color_target = retval.setdefault(color_id, [])
        for phrases in phrase_lists:
            color_found = False
            for phrase in phrases:
                if any(color in phrase for color in color_synonyms):
                    color_target.append(phrase)
                    color_found = True
            if not color_found:
                color_target.append(None)
    return retval

though it seems of little value to just add a None item to the list as there is no way to tell what row of food that None refers to. I think if you wanted to keep track of that you might want a different output. Just my intuition though.

you are not appending 'None' when the condition is not met. the 'r' key should have 'None' as its first value. the goal is to have all dict categories with vals of the same length

how would you append 'none' when the condition is not met ?
